# Export PNG (or other) in multiple versions from PSD with varying background layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, photoshop-scripting

Ive got a website ive mocked up in PS ive got a range of background options which are individual layers in a folder called Backgrounds.

I want to export copies of the website but each time change the background so i have

- website with background 1.png
- website with background 2.png
- website with background 3.png
- .. etc

Is there an automated way to do this ? As ive got around 20 background options and its tedious to keep doing this by hand (im usually exporting versions when a major change is made (update to header etc))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `File > Scripts > Layer Comps to Files`. You can export batches of files based on [layer comps](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/layer-comps.html) that way. Layer comps need to be set up first though, but if you are repeating yourself over and over, it is the lesser of 2 evils.

If you need more control or a better automated script, you will need to [write a custom script](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/cs6/Photoshop-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) to give you that additional flexibility.